# Sub-selects in Outlook 2010 SQL filters?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Outlook 2010 has an "SQL mode" for filters, that allow the user to type a WHERE clause that is used to select the mail shown in the view/folder. In my quest to create a gmail work-a-like view, I would like to filter all messages that are part of a conversation that contains at least one not archived (indicated by a category) message.

Now, of this were real SQL you would do this with a subselect or a join to iterate over all the messages in the source message's conversation. Do we have a similar option using an SQL filter?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a real SQL. This is a SQL DASL. It does not support subqueries.